# anonymous user is not able to see web part settings in sharepoint foundation 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, anonymous-authentication, web-part

I created one anonymous site in sharepoint 2010 and added one web part.
Anonymous user is able to see web part But anonymous user is not able to get web part setting.

thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the web part settings are stored *per user*, this is not possible in an anonymous context.

Comment: thanx Andy..

you mean anonymous user can not change web part settings.

Comment: Yes. As the settings are stored per user, and you don't know who the user is, you can't store the settings - so the anonymous user can't change them.